# For loop in XPath?

Tags: java, regex, xpath, xpath-2.0

For the sample XML below, I need to check if all the /bookstore/book/price ends with "USD".

```
<bookstore>
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00USD</price>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99USD</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

The logic what I've used for this is

```
if(fn:substring(/bookstore/book//Salary/text(), fn:string-length(/bookstore/book//Salary/text())-2 ) = 'USD') then 'true' else 'false'
```

but it fails with "Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring()". 
Yes, the parser is right because fn:substring() accepts only a atomic value but I'm stuck at how to implement this scenario.

Please can anyone shed some light on the logic to implement this Or any function/Operator in XPath?

Just to let you know, My java code running on Linux supports XPath 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: `count()` is often *less* efficient than expressions that have natural shortcuts. See details in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two ways of doing this**: **both may be more efficient** (if the condition is violated midway) than using `count()` which has to traverse the whole sequence:

```
not(/bookstore/book/price[not(ends-with(., 'USD'))])
```

**and**:

```
every $p in /bookstore/book/price 
   satisfies ends-with($p, 'USD')
```

**The latter can be written more compactly as**:

```
every $b in bookstore/book/price/ends-with(., 'USD')
   satisfies $b"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this with an XSL program, using a select in the template matching '/':

```
count(//price[not(ends-with(.,'USD'))])
```

Returns 0 on your XML.